# Issue with java-based app in RMIScoketFactory within locked down environment

Tags: java, windows-security

Our company uses a java application as one of its core business applications - it works fine on the existing Windows 7 environment.

One of (the many) things I'm doing is moving the organization to windows 10 21H2 - with a greater focus on security.

This core business application fails within a secured desktop. By secured, i mean following the CIS Windows 10 lockdown recommendations on an if not/why not basis - so if there is a reason not to follow one, we don't.

After a great deal of troubleshooting, i believe the core of the issue is the following lines from the application

```
Found network address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 (loopback)
Found network address: /127.0.0.1 (loopback)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable network interface found.
 at <appname>/net.MulitopleNetworkadapaterRMISocketfactory.(init)
Couldn't create socketfactory: No suitable network interface found.
```

This occurs running with the firewall off and running from an elevated command prompt - so these basics have been covered off.

I don't know Java at all - and what I'm looking for assistance on is anyone that knows "socketfactory" - how it works. Will it be running all commands in a user security context ? What method does it use to to lookup the local NIC's? I'm trying to work out where it is being blocked.

I'm accepting that it is one of the security lockdowns causing the issue - but I'm having trouble finding it and would like some pointers.

As far as asking the vendor... well... they are not helpful.

I've trawled event logs and process monitor with no success

Comment: Did you try searching the Internet for **debug rmi**?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay on this - the issue ended up being that IPv6 was disabled. Re-enabled that - and the application was happy again.

For others reference -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows